# Swift2 - How does one determine type of thrown error?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, runtime-error, swift2

I wonder how to know what type of an error the function can throw?

For example I see Apple's function throwing error, but I have no idea what to put after `catch` becuase I can't see the type of an error.

I'm trying to print some kind of user info of error or any other description.

Comment: you can catch everything and sort later, see details here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/error-handling-in-swift-2/

Comment: The answer might be to simply read the documentation for the methods whose errors you're interested in catching.

Comment: @nhgrif Documentation is the question. I've searched it and methods just marked as `throws`

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html). Pattern matching is the short answer. Which is good because you can do some really interesting things other than just catch a specific type.

Comment: I've read. It is not answers my question. Becuase in their example they know the type of `VendingMachineError`.

Comment: If you want to see the type as part of the method signature, yes you are right that is not done in Swift. But how is asking a question here going to change that.

Comment: The answer is whoever is throwing should be throwing implementers of the ErrorType Protocol. They should have documented that. The simplest mechanism is to use an Enum, which allows for simple pattern matching with cases in the catch clause.